# How to ouput elements in array in reverse order using while loop in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop

My question is how to output things in the array in reverse order
grouped by two things with resorting only to the while-loop
(i.e., without for-loop and Reverse method, etc.)

I know that the second while-loop is not correct but I do not know how to modify it.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please type four things.");

const int MAX_SIZE = 4;
string[] things = new string[MAX_SIZE];
int i = 0;

while (i < MAX_SIZE)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type the things.");

    things[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    i++;
}

i = 0;

while (i < MAX_SIZE)
{
    Console.Write(things[i] + ", ");
    i--;
}
```

Comment: Clarification: you have an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. You want to output it in next way: (6, 5), (4, 3), (2, 1) using single while loop. Is it correct?

Comment: This is correct, I should output things in pairs separated with comma.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
i = MAX_SIZE - 1
while (i >= 0)
{
    Console.Write(things[i] + ", ");
    i--;
}
```

The reason I am using `MAX_SIZE-1` is because arrays in C# are 0-based. The first element will always be in position 0. If the array has 4 elements, the final element will be in position 3.

If you want to print things in twos, you can just do the following:

```
i = MAX_SIZE - 1
while (i >= 0)
{
    Console.Write(things[i-1] + ", " things[i]);
    i -= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you want to use a while loop instead of a for loop?

```
for(var i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please type the things.");

            things[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            i++;
}

for(var i=MAX_SIZE-1;i>=0;i--){
    Console.Write(things[i] + ", ");
}
```

Comment: probably because it's homework and there is an artificial constraint

Comment: I have imposed this artificial constraint on myself to better understand while loops with arrays. There are constraints everywhere, either in an academic field or work. The above example with the for-loop also looks interesting and useful, I have just had another specific goal in mind.

Comment: Your example has helped me to better understand the logic of the code. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly, next code should work for you:

```
int i = things.Length - 1;
while(i > 0)
{
  Console.Write("({0}, {1}) ", things[i], things[i - 1]);
  i -= 2;
}

//in case the the list lenght is odd, output the last element without pair
if(i == 0)
{
  Console.Write("({0})", things[i]);
}
```

`if` statement can be omitted if `things` list length is always even because it is required only if you need to pring the last (the first in `things` list) element, which has no pair.